# Bind SelectedValue to a WPF combobox

Tags: wpf, combobox, wpf-controls

I've tried searching up and down for this but can't find anything.  I have a combobox in a listview.  The listview is bound to a list of objects exposed through the controller that the datacontext is bound to.  One of the properties of the items in the list is a string.  I'm trying to bind that value to what's in the combobox.

Here is a snippet of my listview

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=OrderLines}" >

            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Item Type" Width="Auto">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox Width="100" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=LineType,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" >

                                    <ComboBoxItem>Type1</ComboBoxItem>
                                    <ComboBoxItem>Type2</ComboBoxItem>
                                    <ComboBoxItem>Type3</ComboBoxItem>
                                    <ComboBoxItem>Type4</ComboBoxItem>
                                </ComboBox>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>    
                </GridView>
             </ListView.View>
```

In the controller I have a property called OrderLines like such

```
    private List<OrderLine> orderLines;
    public List<OrderLine> OrderLines 
    { 
        get { return orderLines; }
        set
        {
            if (value == orderLines)
                return;

            orderLines= value;

            OnPropertyChanged("OrderLines");
        }
    }
```

And an OrderLine just has a property called LineType that is a string that contains the value.

```
    private string lineType;
    public string LineType 
    {
        get { return lineType; }

        set
        {
            lineType= value;
            OnPropertyChanged("LineType ");
        }
    }
```

Can anyone help explain why the selected item/value is not being set.  Does it have something to do with my content being hardcoded?  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It probably doesn't bind because LineType is a string and ComboBox contains ComboBoxItems, and a string != ComboBoxItem.

Try something along

```
 <ComboBox>
      <system:String>Item1</system:String>
      <system:String>Item2</system:String>
 </ComboBox>
```

where system is a namespace referencing System in mscorlib